# How do I include the index of a Pandas Series (data = list of list of dict) into the DataFrame that was created?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

This is how to create my Series:

```
import pandas as pd
stk = pd.Series([[{'stock': 'AAPL', 'amt': 23},
{'stock': 'DIS', 'amt': 52}],
[{'stock': 'IBM', 'amt': 78},
{'stock': 'MSFT', 'amt': 34}]], 
    index=['2023-12-16','2023-12-17'])
print(stk)
```

The print output looks like this:
2023-12-16    [{'stock': 'AAPL', 'amt': 23}, {'stock': 'DIS', 'amt': 52}]
2023-12-17    [{'stock': 'IBM', 'amt': 78}, {'stock': 'MSFT', 'amt': 34}]

When I convert it to a DataFrame with this code:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in stk])
print(df)
```

I get this output:

```
  stock  amt
0  AAPL   23
1   DIS   52
0   IBM   78
1  MSFT   34
```

The date index from the Series is gone.  This is the output that I would like:

```
        dt  stock  amt
2023-12-16  AAPL   23
2023-12-16   DIS   52
2023-12-17   IBM   78
2023-12-17  MSFT   34
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick alternative. `flatten` the Series with `explode` first, and then expand each cell (from a dict) to a Series -

```
stk.explode().apply(pd.Series)

           stock  amt
2023-12-16  AAPL   23
2023-12-16   DIS   52
2023-12-17   IBM   78
2023-12-17  MSFT   34
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v,index = [k]*len(v)) for k,v in stk.items()])
```

Output:

```
           stock  amt
2023-12-16  AAPL   23
2023-12-16   DIS   52
2023-12-17   IBM   78
2023-12-17  MSFT   34
```